# Try & Catch — How do you use them effectively?

Tags: javascript, debugging, error-handling, try-catch

I've been trying to teach myself JavaScript, and one thing I was reading on is the try/catch structure.  Unfortunately, the tutorial doesn't provide much explanation on how it would be useful, just how to set it up.  Can anyone offer some insight?

Comment: [MDC try...catch statement documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#try...catch_Statement) has some solid examples you should be able to follow.

Comment: Are you asking just about JavaScript or PHP as well?

Comment: I program in PHP already and am learning JavaScript, so both.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a intensive function, I wouldn't recommend using try-catch.You can refer this doc for a good explanation: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/JavaScript_Performance_Best_Practices#Don.27t_use_try-catch-finally_inside_performance-critical_functions

Basically, It creates a second activation object in the context chain and hence your lookups take more time.